# Create Modeless Form - starts on top

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

[**Warning** - this is a trap for young players, you would normally never put any of your UI stuff to run in separate threads as the correct way is to put your long processing work into background threads instead. However, this solution was required due to the limitations of a legacy system.]

We have a fairly complicated application and wish to have a general-purpose modeless form that pops up over all the other (both modal and modeless) forms, with a caption (set new each time asked to show) and a spinning gif to show the user that there is background processing going on. This can get called from multiple places to start, and all overlapping, the last call should get to set the title/comment.

However, the original code did not always show up the form, and never showed it above the current modal form:

```
Private Sub StartLongRunningProcess(comment As String, title As String)
    LongRunningProcess.MdiParent = MainForm
    '...set title and comment here....
    LongRunningProcess.Show()
    LongRunningProcess.BringToFront()
    DoCenter(LongRunningProcess, MainForm)
    MainForm.Refresh()
End Sub
Public Sub HideLongRunningProcess()
    LongRunningProcess.Hide()
End Sub
```

I've tried improving things by:

- using actual objects instead of their classes
- using a normal, non-Mdi, modeless form that I start with:

  ```
  _longRunningProcess = New LongRunningProcess(frmPC9main)
  ```
- `.TopMost = True`
- using `.Activate()` instead of `.BringToFront()`
- even creating the `_longRunningProcess` in a separate thread such as suggested [here](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/25387696/A-modeless-form-that-is-really-modeless.html) which *almost* works except that it puts up the message "(Not Responding)" sometimes, which will make the user think to force-quit the application... the exact thing we're trying to avoid when they have long-running processes. BTW, I can't put my long-running processes into background threads as there are just too many, not possible to do with all anyway - they all need access to the main thread.

This really should be such a basic thing to accomplish, am I missing something?

Also note: apart from show/hide of the form, I don't need any other interaction with it.

[edit] The threading I've been trying is:

```
Dim _longRunningProcessThread As Thread
Private _longRunningProcess As LongRunningProcess = Nothing

Public Sub ShowLongRunningProcess(Optional ByVal comment As String = "", Optional ByVal title As String = "Processing in background")
     MainForm.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False

    If _longRunningProcess Is Nothing Then
        _longRunningProcessThread = New Thread(New ThreadStart(Sub() StartLongRunningProcess()))
        _longRunningProcessThread.IsBackground = True
        _longRunningProcessThread.Start()
    Else
        _longRunningProcess.setCaption(comment)
        _longRunningProcess.setTitle(title)
        _longRunningProcess.Show()
        _longRunningProcess.Activate()
        DoCenter(_longRunningProcess, _mainForm)
        _mainForm.Refresh()
        _longRunningProcess.Refresh()
        Application.DoEvents()
    End If


    MainForm.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = True

End Sub

Private Sub StartLongRunningProcess()
    If _longRunningProcess Is Nothing Then
        _longRunningProcess = New LongRunningProcess(_mainForm) 
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub HideLongRunningProcess()
    MainForm.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False
    _longRunningProcess.Hide()
    MainForm.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = True
End Sub
```

This now will appear on top, but when the main thread is accessing the db it shows as (not responding).

Comment: Definitely not the right approach here in your edit. Let me put something together for you.

Comment: The standard mistake is to do this the wrong way around, displaying the form on a worker thread and have the UI thread perform the "long running" code.  Many excessively nasty problems with this, starting with the form having no Z-order relationship at all with any other window in your app.  As you found out.  And usually not ending soon enough by the dreadful problem of the SystemEvents class events getting fired on the wrong thread, causing arbitrary deadlock long after this form is closed.  Use the UI thread to display UI, long running code belongs in a worker thread.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm working with legacy code from over 30 years ago (it use to use FoxPro db!)....I can't change everything that should be in the background to run in the background. I would if I could... but that's just not a practical solution now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a version of the code that runs on seperate threads. The code you provided above wasn't running a message loop on the second thread. Also setting CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false is a really bad idea for what you're trying to achieve.

Usage:

```
    ProgressForm.Initialise()

    ProgressForm.ShowProgressForm("hello", "hello")

    Dim modalForm As New Form With {.Text = "MyModalForm"}
    modalForm.ShowDialog()

    ProgressForm.HideProgressForm()

    ProgressForm.TearDown()
```

And here's the ProgressForm definition.

```
Public Class ProgressForm
    Inherits Form

    Private Shared sForm As ProgressForm
    Private Shared sThread As Thread

    Public Sub New()
        Me.TopMost = True
        Me.BackColor = Color.Green
        Me.Text = "Progress"
    End Sub

    Public Shared Sub Initialise()
        'Create the form
        sThread = New Thread(AddressOf ThreadFunc)
        sThread.Start()
        While sForm Is Nothing OrElse sForm.InvokeRequired = False
            Thread.Sleep(0)
        End While
    End Sub

    Public Shared Sub TearDown()
        sForm.BeginInvoke(Sub() Application.ExitThread())
    End Sub

    Private Shared Sub ThreadFunc()
        sForm = New ProgressForm
        'Dim handle = sForm.Handle
        Application.Run(sForm)
    End Sub

    Public Shared Sub ShowProgressForm(caption As String, title As String)
        If sForm.InvokeRequired Then
            sForm.BeginInvoke(Sub() ShowProgressForm(caption, title))
        Else
            sForm.Text = title
            'TODO: Caption
            sForm.Visible = True
            sForm.TopMost = True
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Shared Sub HideProgressForm()
        If sForm.InvokeRequired Then
            sForm.BeginInvoke(Sub() HideProgressForm())
        Else
            sForm.Visible = False
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub ProgressForm_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
        If e.CloseReason = CloseReason.UserClosing Then
            Me.Visible = False
            e.Cancel = True
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Hi @FloatingKiwi that was pretty close to perfect...just had to add the instance of the form to the Application.Run call (I've made an edit but it is awaiting peer review). I also set to topmost on show as I initialise it once then use show/hide regularly. Thank you for showing the right way to do something wrong!

Answer (score 0):

`.TopMost = true` on the form will lift it above all other windows. However when you open a modal dialog it will steal the event loop so you wont be able to interact with that form. If your form doesn't need interaction though this approach should work.

Here's a quick example of running the form on a different thread (although you shouldn't use the threadpool for this kind of a task)

```
    Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(Sub()
                                               Dim form As New Form With {.TopMost = True, .Text = "Progress", .BackColor = Color.Red}
                                               Application.Run(form)
                                           End Sub)

    Dim modalForm As New Form With {.Text = "MyModalForm"}
    modalForm.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: ah, actually, .TopMost = True was the first thing I tried. Thanks, I'll add it to my list.

Comment: What was the problem with .TopMost = True? Are you trying to popup this form over an existing TopMost form?

Comment: I need this form to be modeless. And yes, I'm trying to get it to popup over any other form in the application, which is sometimes a modal form (would they not be topmost?)

Comment: See the example in my edit above. Does this not popup above the modal form on your pc?

Comment: Yeah, my threaded example does that too... but still show (not responding)

Comment: Does the progress form show not responding, or your main application form? The Application.Run(form) will ensure that the progress form has a functioning message loop which should never block because you're not doing anything with it. Your modal form however will block its message loop everytime you do a long running operation. To keep the form responsive you need to shift the long running task onto a background thread. The background worker control is useful for doing this.